# Super slow SSD write speeds with RAID 1

Tags: performance, ssd, raid-1

I have a very new computer system, configured in RAID 1, but was surprised that the write speeds were extremely slow!

Here is a snapshot of my computer setup:

- Motherboard: Asus Z9PE-D8 WS Workstation Motherboard - Intel C602 Chipset
- Processor:  2x Intel Xeon E5-2630 V2 2.6/3.1GHz Turbo 15MB Cache 6-core (12 core)
- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate
- Hard Drive Bay One:  750GB Samsung 840 EVO SSD
- Hard Drive Bay Two:  750GB Samsung 840 EVO SSD
- RAID 1 utilizing LSI RAID Configuration

Here were the results of my Crystal Disk Mark 3.03 tests (I performed 3 tests and this was the best result)

- Sequential Read [MB/s]: **588.3** // Sequential Write [MB/s]: **50.22**

Yes, that is a 50.22, not a 500.22...
Now, my friend had the a similar setup with RAID 1 configuration and his results were

- Sequential Read [MB/s]: **594.7** // Sequential Write [MB/s]: **493.1**

I am trying to figure out what I need to do to get my write speeds similar to his, but after updating the BIOS, reconfiguring stuff, etc. I cannot seem to find any solution.

Comment: 840 evo and pro have nearly identical read speeds, but the pro blows away the evo on write.  Is it possible your friend has the pros?

Comment: He has the PROs, but 50 is substantially different from 493. I would expect at least a 350 mb/s write speed if we were to be comparing the two

Comment: Did you do the same tests without the raid config? To validate there isn't a hardware fault with a drive?